# evaluating JBPM version 6.2 and problems

Tags: spring, tomcat, jbpm, kie, kie-workbench

I am new to JBPM (evaluating version 6.2), I already worked almost 4 year in activiti bpm, Can someone explain me following things

- I already created a process and domain entity with kie workbench and deployed it into my application (tested both way with copy past kjar and integrate with maven repo), my application and kie workbench is pointing to same database and currently deployed to same tomcat, is it correct?
- I have already been able to start the process from kie workbench as well as from my application, but the process which I deployed/started from my own application is visible in kie workbench and vice versa,but i am unable to take any action like completing the task from kie workbench, what could be the possible reason ? (possible session related issue)
- what will happened if i update already running process and deployed the update version (off course i have to set -Dorg.kie.override.deploy.enabled=true, and same olde version), what will be the impact on already running process? I am getting following error with my demo app

"Unexpected error encountered : java.lang.RuntimeException:Could not find process demoWorkflow.shipmentProcess when restoring process instance 1"

- what will happened if i have more then one instance of my application (cluster) pointing to same JBPM database, and what kind strategy should I used to deploy the updated process on all instances with kie workbench. We don't want to restart our servers.
- if I modify the module (update the bpmn as well as data model) and deploy it again, what will be the impact on existing process.
- kie guvnor is replaced kie-scanner, its mean that every time we are changing the drool rules we have to rely on kie-scanner to update the rule inside my process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: anybody there to answer above questions ???? Thanks